# php redirect triggers warning from page that is redirect to

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to redirect my domain name to my corporate sub domain site. I have used php to redirect the page but when I try to go there Firefox gives me the following warning.

"You are about to log in to the site "######.com" with the username "myRedirect", but the website does not require authentication. This may be an attempt to trick you.

Is "#####.com" the site you want to visit?"

When I click yes it sends me to the top level domain and not my sub domain. I have no control over the corporate domain or the sub domain.

I have used both of these methods:

```
<?php
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://myRedirect@subdomain.com'>";
?>

<?php
header("http://myRedirect@subdomain.com");
?>
```

Is there a way to do the redirect as not to trigger the warning event?

Comment: you're using wrong url myRedirect@ means redirect to subdomain.com with user myRedirect, you should replace you whole link with `http://mysubdomain.domain.com`

Comment: Ahem, `header('Location: ...')`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo and / or incorrect use of [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/function.header.php)

Comment: Duh I can't believe I didn't see the typo. I was just doing a copy and paste and never bothered to read. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that you put url `http://myRedirect@subdomain.com` which is user `myRedirect` without password and `subdomain.com` as domain but this only work if that page have HTTP Authenication. (popup prompt to enter user and password when call without user and password).

to redirect you should use url `subdomain.domain.com` and another thing is that in php you need to use Location header.

```
header('Location: subdomain.domain.com');
```